# Name of the English speaking test where you have to describe a scene

Tags: terminology, esl

There is a well-known English Communication test which is used to assess primary and middle-school students' levels of *spoken* English.  Students look at a scene card where several  activities are taking place (for example, Scene: Hiking: "The man with the hat is hiking;  The man with the walking cane is tired.  The woman at the top is reading a book.")

Students are free to say whatever they want and use any words they know in English: the goal is for the students to accurately describe what they see usually within a time limit. The test is seen as an opportunity for students to improve their fluency.

What is this type of test called in English?  Below, you can see an image that is very similar to the images seen in the test.

[image: children fight angrily over a toy; a toddler crawls up the slide; a man and a woman enjoy talking over a book.]

I'm looking for the specific name of the test. It does seem like the Thematic Apperception Test, but they use these cartoon-like images. This is a really hard question to answer, and I've been trying to contact people in Japan to find an answer to this problem. I encountered this type of test at a failing middle school in Kashiwa, I think.

Comment: iMerchant What's the name of the test.

Comment: But actually, this isn't a question about the English language is it? It's about a teaching method -- "Students may ... use any language". An actual question might be on-topic on [CogSci.SE]; here, there isn't a question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach No, this is a standard EFL test that is exclusively used for assessing students who are learning English.  It isn't an all-languages test.  If you know of an international test that is similar, that would also be useful, but I have never seen a similar test for Spanish, Japanese, French, or Chinese.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Given that "students can use any language", it would not be difficult to produce a test for any language, even if you use cards designed for students of English.

Comment: @iMerchant This is a typical identification format for a question.  State what you hope to define with upwards inflection (spoken English).  This would be useful, but the down-vote decreases the question's visibility, so it really isn't helpful at all.  In fact, it's just a waste of time.  It's very difficult and time-consuming to connect to this site, and down-vote spam is counter-productive.  You should wait to see if the question improves before hammering the critic button, and you should also probably consider the correctness of your comments.  Beyond that, you can click "edit", also.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's the LinguaFranca.  You can always use any language.  So, by your logic, we should delete every question on the site.

Comment: On the contrary, all open questions are specifically about the English **language**. This question does now ask a question; it's been re-opened and it's eligible to have downvotes given to a previous version reversed. Now that it is actually a question, the community can answer it, or do anything else the system allows.

Comment: When you say students may "use any language" do you mean that they can answer in English or French or Klingon, at their preference, or do you mean that they can use any (English) vocabulary? If the latter, you should edit the question, as I think that's where the confusion is coming from. (It sounds a little like the Thematic Apperception Test, but presumably scored on much different criteria.)

Comment: I'm going to be really boring and say that it is called a *speaking test*.  Aimed at young learners,  it can involve telling a story based on a series of vignettes, describing the differences between two pictures, describing a photo for a minute, listening to the examiner's instructions and pointing to the relevant objects in a scene card, identifying which is the odd one out in a series of images, and explaining why, etc. there are other ways of testing students' vocabulary level. It's mostly vocab stuff, and basic grammar.

Comment: @1006a Okay, I see what you mean.  I mean they may use any English (written, oral, any structures) to describe the scene.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you.  It's supposed to be an English Communication test, I think, because I encountered it in Japan when I was teaching that subject.  I'm looking for the specific name of the test.  It does seem like the Thematic Appreciation Test, but they use these cartoon-like images.  Maybe the test is not as popular as I had thought, though I have heard the name in several places.  If I am wrong, it might be a test popularly used by a publisher or series author, only.  But I hope to find the name of the test because it was very fun and useful, and there was a lot of great content.

Comment: You could look up ESL or EFL speaking test materials for young learners. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - I never downvoted you, btw, hence my question and my suggestion in the comments. (I very rarely DV anything actually). I was just guessing as to why others did.

Comment: @iMerchant My bad.  My job is very stressful.  I didn't mean to snap off at people.  Anyway, this is a really hard question to answer.  I've been trying to contact people in Japan to find the correct answer.  I encountered the test at a failing middle school in Kashiwa, I think.

Comment: I appear to have misdiagnosed this as being spam, but I still believe that it is a request for (probably publisher-specific) resources.

Answer (score 2):

The best suggestion I can offer is **[picture prompts](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22picture+prompts%22+speaking)**.

In the Cambridge English Preliminary Exam, level B1, (aka PET), each candidate is given a detailed [colour photo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YyY2GHcF8A) which they have to describe within a minute.

In Cambridge Young Learners' exams, students taking [**Starters**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEXL_IpFzUQ) have to recognize and identify the objects in the image; candidates in [**Movers**](https://youtu.be/ncLgGQJJWOI?t=30s) are given two pictures in which to identify the differences while in **[Flyers](https://youtu.be/F5zBBXOdd9Y?t=29s)**, candidates have to explain why their picture is different from the examiner's.

Some other examples from the web

- *[Testing Second Language Speaking](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r2SuBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&lpg=PT95&dq=%22picture%20prompts%22%20speaking%20test&source=bl&ots=IqwSAw9MWk&sig=qxc5HETkzi1a-9sh9x0BqohK9_o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwwr3cnq7TAhUPZFAKHa-fCCgQ6AEITjAL#v=onepage&q=%22picture%20prompts%22%20speaking%20test&f=false)* By Glenn Fulcher
- British Council
  http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/exams/speaking-exams/describe-photo-or-picture
- British Council
  http://esol.britishcouncil.org/content/learners/skills/speaking/describing-picture-family-scene
- Cambridge *Flyers*, Speaking test, part 3
  http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/images/cambridge-english-flyers-speaking-part-3.pdf
- Boggles World (for very young learners)
  http://bogglesworldesl.com/picture_descriptions.htm